# Why is there an injected class name?

Tags: c++

Recently, I saw a strange C++ feature: *injected class name*.

```
class X { };
X x1;
class X::X x2; // class X::X is equal to X
class X::X::X x3; // ...and so on...
```

But I cannot figure out why this feature is necessary. Is there any practice that requires this feature?

And I heard this feature didn't exist in old C++. Then, when was it introduced? C++03? C++11?

Answer (score 184, accepted):

The injected class name means that `X` is declared as a member of `X`, so that name lookup inside `X` always finds the current class, not another `X` that might be declared at the same enclosing scope, e.g.

```
void X() { }
class X {
public:
  static X create() { return X(); }
};
```

Is the `create()` function creating a temporary `X` object or calling the function `X`? At namespace scope it would call the function, so the purpose of the injected-class-name is to ensure that within the body of `X` the name always finds the class itself (because name lookup starts in the class' own scope before looking in the enclosing scope).

It's also helpful inside class templates, where the injected class name can be used without a template argument list, e.g. using simply `Foo` instead of the full template-id `Foo<blah, blah, blah>`, so it's easy to refer to the current instantiation. See [DR 176](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#176) for a change between C++98 and C++03 that clarified that.

The idea of the injected class name was present in C++98, but the terminology was new for C++03.

C++98 says:

> A *class-name* is inserted into the scope in which it is declared immediately after the *class-name* is seen. The class-name is also inserted into the scope of the class itself.

The second sentence was changed by [DR 147](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#147) so C++03 says in [class]/2:

> A *class-name* is inserted into the scope in which it is declared immediately after the *class-name* is seen. The *class-name* is also inserted into the scope of the class itself; this is known as the *injected-class-name*.

Even before C++98, the ARM has roughly equivalent wording that means the class' name can always be used in the class body to refer to the class itself:

> The name of a class can be used as a *class-name* even within the *member-list* of the class specifier itself.
>
> > - For example,
> >
> >   > *`class link { link* next; };`*

Comment: I got asked that pretty often, but never could build up a simple example pointing the problem. So +1 For the example.

Comment: This can be seen clearly if you run clang++ your_program.cpp -Xclang -ast-dump and you see your class and then an injected class child node.

Comment: note that `X()` is `void` so you can't actually `return X()` even if it can looks up that function

Comment: @phuclv yes, but that's not really the point here. If it bothers you, change the global function to `int X();` and then add a constructor `X(int)` to the class, so that if lookup did find the function, it might be usable. The main point still holds: the injected-class-name ensures the class itself is found, not something else with that name.

Answer (score -1):

I Have recently stumbled upon a similar issue. I'm more familiar with C++ so when I tried to define a linked_list struct in C, it won't let me declare the next pointer without using declaring it again within the struct:

```
struct Node
{
  int data;
  Node* next; // You can use 'Node' without 'struct' in C++
};
```

but in C, Node isn't known within the Node sturct and therefore we have to declare it as follows :

```
struct node
{
  int data;
  struct node *next;
};
```

I hope this helps on why they added this feature.

Comment: My understanding is that this is not due to injected class names and instead due to the fact that in C, you can’t declare a variable of struct type without including the keyword “struct,” hence the “typedef struct” idiom.