# Is it legal to (accidentally) specify a classname twice when calling a static function?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012, gcc, clang

My collegue just ran our codebase through a new compiler for a new platform, and unsurprisingly there were errors that had not been reported before.

One of them concerned code where the original author had accidentally typed a class name twice when calling a static function of that class.  The looked like this:

```
class Thing
{
public:
    static void DoStuff ();
};

int main (int, char **)
{
    Thing::Thing::DoStuff();
    // or even: Thing::Thing::Thing::Thing::Thing::Thing::DoStuff();
    return 0;
}
```

GCC 4.9.2 on my local (Cygwin) machine compiles it fine, even with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic`.  A customized Clang that we're using for an embedded system also accepts it.  Visual Studio 2012 (v110) gives me the error:

```
error C3083: '{ctor}': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
```

I can imagine equally convincing arguments for:

1. It's legal and the compiler accepts it. (*i.e.* GCC and Clang are correct, VS is wrong)
2. It's not legal, but the compiler may accept it anyway.
3. It's legal but the compiler doesn't accept it. (*i.e.* VS is wrong; maybe it's a new C++11 thing that hasn't been added yet?)
4. It's not legal and the compiler shouldn't accept it. (*i.e.* Visual Studio is the only correct one)
5. Just fix the error and get on with my life.

Which one is correct?

Comment: I hardly believe it should work since in the Thing class there is not another class or namespace called Thing.

Comment: The name of the class is injected into the scope of the class itself, so this should be fine, even to arbitrary levels of repetition.

Comment: @Melkon yes there is : the [injected class name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549652/c-why-is-there-injected-class-name).

Comment: @Quentin: Whao, thanks, i didn't knew this. :o I think abusing this is avoidable tho, and i see no advantage of this.

Comment: The injected class name is the answer, but there's a lot to be said for option 5.