# Cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Component<W> *' to 'Component<W> *'

Tags: c++, templates

I created a small sample which demonstrates the problem. I sure don't understand whats going wrong here. Using Visual Studio 2010.

The classes are (very loosely) modeled after `MFC` because this is what I need to use it for.
Basically I wanted to create a panel class, which can contain other panels or controls so I added a component class which keeps track of the id and the parent, and the panel class which acts as a container for it's components.

Now what I don't understand is why I get this compiler error and why I get it only when I use a control but not with a subpanel.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

class CWnd
{
public:
    CWnd(CWnd *pParent = NULL, int nId = -1)
    {
        mId = nId;
        mParent = pParent;
        mClassname = NULL;
    }

    void setId(int nId) { mId = nId; }
    int getId(void) const { return mId; }

    void setParent(CWnd *pParent) { mParent = pParent; }
    CWnd *getParent(void) const { return mParent; }

    bool create(const char *pClassname, int nId, CWnd *pParent)
    {
        mId = nId;
        mParent = pParent;
        mClassname = pClassname;

        return true;
    }

private:
    int mId;
    CWnd *mParent;
    const char *mClassname;
};

class Ctrl : public CWnd
{
public:
    Ctrl(CWnd *pParent, int nId = -1)
        : CWnd(pParent, nId)
    {
    }
};

class Dialog : public CWnd
{
public:
    Dialog(CWnd *pParent, int nId = -1)
        : CWnd(pParent, nId)
    {
    }

    bool create(int nId, CWnd *pParent)
    {
        CWnd::create("dialog", nId, pParent);

        return true;
    }
};

class View : public CWnd
{
public:
    View(CWnd *pParent = NULL)
        : CWnd(pParent)
    {
    }
};

template <typename W>
class Component : public W
{
public:
    Component(CWnd *pParent = NULL)
        : W(pParent)
    {
        mId = -1;
        mParent = pParent;
    }

    virtual bool create(CWnd *pParent = NULL)
    {
        if(pParent)
            mParent = pParent;

        W::setParent(mParent);
        W::setId(mId);

        return true;
    }

private:
    int mId;
    CWnd *mParent;
};

class Panel : public Component<Dialog>
{
public:
    Panel(CWnd *pParent = NULL)
        : Component(pParent)
    {
    }

    virtual bool create(CWnd *pParent = NULL)
    {
        if(pParent != NULL)
            setParent(pParent);

        Dialog::create(getId(), pParent);

        for(Components::iterator it = mComponents.begin(); it != mComponents.end(); ++it)
        {
            if(!(*it)->create(this))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    void addComponent(Component *pComponent)
    {
        if(std::find(mComponents.begin(), mComponents.end(), pComponent) == mComponents.end())
            mComponents.push_back(pComponent);
    }

    void removeComponent(Component *pComponent)
    {
        Components::iterator pos = std::find(mComponents.begin(), mComponents.end(), pComponent);
        if(pos != mComponents.end())
            mComponents.erase(pos);
    }

protected:
    typedef std::vector<Component *> Components;

private:
    Components mComponents;
};

int main()
{
    View v;
    Panel d;
    Panel p;
    Component<Ctrl> listbox;
    Component<Ctrl> tab;

    // these are generating the error
    d.addComponent(&listbox);
    d.addComponent(&tab);

    // only this one works.
    d.addComponent(&p);

    std::cout << "\nDone! Press any key..." << std::endl;
    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

The error message that I get is:

```
'Panel::addComponent' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Component<W> *' to 'Component<W> *'
```

Comment: The `Component` in addComponent is actually a `Component<Dialog>` (since that's the type seen in the class) so you cannot pass a `Component<Ctrl>` to it

Comment: Is that the actual compiler error you get?

Comment: @juanchopanza, yes. Which I find kind of funny. :)

Comment: GCC gives a more sensible error: `no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Component<Ctrl>*' to 'Component<Dialog>*'`

Comment: Such an error would have been more helpfull .)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no type `Component`, so there is no type `Component*`. However, in the context of the `Panel` class, since it is derived from `Component<Dialog>`, the name `Component` is actually injected, and refers to `Component<Dialog>`. So the proper signature of `addComponent` is:

```
void addComponent(Component<Dialog> *pComponent)
```

But `Component<Ctrl>` does not derive from `Component<Dialog>`, so a `Component<Ctrl>*` cannot be passed to this function.

What you might want to do is derive `Component` from a second base class (which is not derived from anything).

```
class Component_base
{
    // component common functionality
};

template<typename W>
class Component : public W, public Component_base
{
    ...
};
```

Then your `Panel` class can store:

```
std::vector<Component_base*> Components;
```

Comment: But I specifically did NOT specify the type in `addComponent` so shouldn't it take ANY component as it's argument? That was my idea (similar to a Java generic Component<?>), I would have thought that it should deduce the type from the parameter and not from the class its used in. That's normaly the way that arguments work, right?

Comment: @Devolus: No. There is no such thing as a `Component*`, because `Component` is not a type. However, in the context of the `Panel` class, the name is injected and actually refers to `Component<Dialog>` (because `Panel` derives from `Component<Dialog>`.

Comment: If you want to have a common base class for all `Component<...>` classes, you must have `Component<W>` derive from some non-template `Component` base class: `class Component { ... }; template <class W> class Component : public Component { ... };`

Comment: At least I understand now the problem. I thought that Component refers to an unspecified type of Component<W> where W can be anything.

Comment: @JohnB, I know, but then I get the diamond problem, which I wanted to avoid :)

Comment: Diamond problem? Where?

Comment: @Devolus: No need for a diamond. The base class does not need to be derived from anything.

Comment: Because my conponent will be a BaseComponent as well as an MFC class.

Comment: OK. I have to give that a try and see if that works as I intended it.

Comment: @Devolus: You might want to have a look at this talk, I guess: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIhUE5uUFOA It is about avoiding deep inheritance hierarchies when interfacing existing frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

There is something called [injected-class-name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25549652/2069064). For class templates, this means that within the scope of the class template the class template name refers to the specific instantiation - not the template itself:

```
template <class T>
class C {
    C(C<T> const& ) = default; // one way to write the copy constructor
    C(C const& ) = default;    // exactly equivalent to the above
};
```

Inherited classes inherit all the injected class names as well. So when you write:

```
class Panel : public Component<Dialog>
```

we have multiple different injected names: `Panel`, `Component`, `Dialog`, and `CWnd`. It's the second one that's significant: within the scope of `Panel`, `Component` refers to the specific class `Component<Dialog>` and **not** the class template `Component`. Thus:

```
void addComponent(Component *pComponent)
```

is shorthand for (and exactly equivalent to):

```
void addComponent(Component<Dialog> *pComponent)
```

There is no class relationship between `Component<Dialog>` and `Component<Ctrl>`, hence the error.

---

Based on your comments, you actually wanted this to be a function template. So you have to explicitly make it one:

```
template <class W>
void addComponent(Component<W> *pComponent) { ... }
```

But this won't work since you're holding onto a `vector<Component<Dialog>*>`. You'll need to change that as well - perhaps to `vector<CWnd*>`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Templates always provide a new confusion for me, when I think that I finally understood it a little bit. :) Since I have to store it in an array, It boils down to creating a common base class.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that there is no conversion from `Component<Ctrl>*` to `Component<Dialog>*`. `d.addComponent(&p);` works because `d` and `p` are the same type. You need to create common base class for `Component<Ctrl>*` and `Component<Dialog>*` to make such conversion or create converting constructor between those 2 types.