# call base class constructor without naming its class

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

```
class MyDerived: public Incredble<Difficult< And<Complicated, Long>>, And<Even, Longer>, BaseClass, Name>
{
public:
  MyDerived();
}


MyDerived::MyDerived
: ???(params)
{}
```

Is there any way to call a base constructor without writing its full name and without typedeffing it?

The reason is clearly to avoid code duplication and introducing multiple positions to change if a detail in the base class template params changes.

Level 2 of this:

```
template <uint32 C>
class MyDerived: public Incredble<Difficult< And<Complicated, Long>>, And<Even, Longer>, BaseClass, Name>
{
public:
  MyDerived();
}

template <uint32 C>
MyDerived::MyDerived<C> 
: ???(C)
{
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `using` or `typedef`?

Comment: its polluting the enclosing namespace

Comment: depending on your constructor you can use `using`  and constructor delegation (which does not pollute namespace). Depends if you have issues with parameters or templates.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch: You can use a `typedef` in an anonymous `namespace { ... }` so it doesn't leak outside of its .cpp file.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use [*injected-class-name*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25549652/2069064). `Incredible<...>::Incredible` refers to itself, and since `MyDerived` isn't a class template, unqualified lookup will look in the scope of its base classes:

```
MyDerived::MyDerived
: Incredble(params)
{}
```

If `Incredible` is a *dependent* name, then you need to qualify it. You can actually simply use the derived type name to qualify the base class's *injected-class-name* (h/t [Johannes Schaub-litb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34509/johannes-schaub-litb)):

```
MyDerived::MyDerived
: MyDerived::Incredible(params)
{}
```

This will work in all cases.

Comment: does this change if MyDerived is a classe tempate? because it is for me but the template parameter. i can add this to the initial question

Comment: detail namespaces are always nice.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch The answer already addresses this case - you can't use injected-class-name, but you can always add an alias or alias template in a non-public namespace

Comment: If it is a class template, `: MyDerived::Incredible(params) { }` should just work.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb **Wow.** That's the trick I've been missing. That seems superior to all the other solutions here and worthy of its own answer. So qualifying with the derived class name makes the injected base class type visible when the base is a template. I guess that makes sense, given that we have to use `this->` to get at its members, etc. I just might never have thought of trying it without you pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't wont to use `using` or `typedef` to avoid "polluting the enclosing namespace", you can use `using` inside the class/struct.

An example

```
#include <map>

template <typename ...>
class foo
 {};

struct A : public foo<int, std::tuple<long, char, std::map<std::string, int>>>
 {
   using base_t = foo<int, std::tuple<long, char, std::map<std::string, int>>>;

   A () : base_t{}
    { };
 };

int main()
 { }
```

Comment: You used the `Incredble` class name two times.

Comment: @Liviu - that's right; but you can use `base_t` for other purposes in the same class (other constructors, by example); to avoid the duplication you can define `base_t` outside the struct but you pollute the external namespace

Comment: deriving from stl object is in general no good idea. I mean the idea is OK but the example is bad

Comment: @Hayt - I'm agree; modified example.

Comment: @max66 "you pollute the external namespace" only if you dump the typedef in it without thinking to use a local detail namespace or w/e.