# Class with template argument and crtp, constructor call by class name only

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I'm not sure what I should search for, so I'm sorry if this question have already been asked.

I have the following code

```cpp
namespace ns {
    template<typename crtp> struct  base_type {
        template<typename ...Args> base_type(Args &&...args);
    };
}

struct derived_type: ns::base_type<derived_type> {
    derived_type(int a, float b): base_type{a, b} {}
};

template<typename template_arg>
struct derived_template_type: ns::base_type<derived_template_type<template_arg>> {
    derived_template_type(int a, float b): base_type{a, b} {}
};
```

`derived_type` compiles fine. `derived_template_type` fails to compile with following error (clang, c++17):

```
error: member initializer 'base_type' does not name a non-static data member or base class
    derived_template_type(int a, float b): base_type{a, b} {}
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

To make it work, I have to replace this usage of `base_type` with it's fully-qualified name `ns::base_type<derived_template_type<template_arg>>` - so basically repeat what is already there on the base classes' list.

First question is: why is it so? The compiler should be aware that this is the base class, know where it's located and what are its template parameters - like in case of `derived_type` - but apparently, it's not. Which language rule causes it to behave this way?

Second question is (obviously): can I do something to avoid this repeating?

Comment: [call base class constructor without naming its class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39413091/call-base-class-constructor-without-naming-its-class) is the closest candidate duplicate I found.

Comment: I wonder why it accept ```derived_type(int a, float b): base_type{a, b} {}``` in case of ```struct derived_type: ns::base_type<derived_type>```. To me that is more of a strange behavior! :)

Comment: @cpplearner thanks, this indeed looks like a solution for me - using "derived_template_type::base_type" seems to solve the problem (it's apparently called "injected class name"). So it seems to answer my second question. I'd still like to know what's going on there (my "first question").

Comment: The explanation provided in the answer for [Compiler Error When Calling Base Constructor when both Base and Derived are Templated With Derived Type Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43712270/compiler-error-when-calling-base-constructor-when-both-base-and-derived-are-temp/43712304#43712304) seems good enough to me.

Comment: @cpplearner you're right, it explains everything. Thanks again. Apparently I was too confused to properly formulate the search query. I guess, my question can be closed as a duplicate.