# Return class ref from class template function

Tags: c++, templates

Given a class template:

```
template <typename T>
class my_class
{
public:
    my_class& test1() { return *this; }
    // OR
    my_class<T>& test2() { return *this; }
}
```

Is there any difference between return types of `test1` and `test2`?

Comment: No, there is no difference

Comment: No. ( potatoes)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any difference between return types of `test1` and `test2`?

No. There is a concept called [injected-class-name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25549652/2069064). Within the body of `my_class<T>`, the name `my_class` refers to the full type `my_class<T>`.

We can even take this to its logical conclusion and add:

```
my_class::my_class::my_class::my_class& test4() { return *this; }
```

Comment: Needs more `my_class`.

Comment: injected class name behaves differently in c++03 and c++11, can you add that?

Comment: @Trevir I'm not aware of a change in C++11.

Comment: In c++11 it is possible to used the injected class name as a template argument for a template-template parameter. This was not possible in c++03.

Answer (score 2):

No, within the scope `my_class<T>`, `my_class` is an abbreviation for `my_class<T>`.