# How do I overload % operator for a template class?

Tags: c++, class, templates, overloading, operator-keyword

I created a template class Number. I overloaded << operator but I'm not able to get % operator working.

```
template<typename t>
class Number
{
private:
    t n;
public:
    Number(t a) :n{ a } {};
    Number() :n{ t() } {};
    friend ostream & operator<<<>(ostream & os, const Number<t>& a);
    friend Number<t> operator%(Number<t> a, Number<t> b);
};
template<typename t>
ostream & operator<<<>(ostream & os, Number<t> a)
{
    os << a.n;
    return os;
}
template<typename t> 
Number<t> operator%(Number<t> a, Number<t> b)
{
    return Number<t>(a.n % b.n);
}
```

As you can see <> in << operator definition, that does the job for it. But if I use that in % operator definition, I get a syntax error and if I don't I get 
"1 unresolved external" error. So my problem can be summed up in two questions-
1. Why do we need to use <> while overloading operator using friend notation?
2. Why its not working for % operator?

Comment: Darn good question. I have no good answer, you need someone who groks templates far better than I, but I know the problem goes away if you move the function definition into the class: `friend Number<t> operator%(Number<t> a, Number<t> b)
    {
        return Number<t>(a.n % b.n);
    }` Crap answer, so it's a comment, but it's what I do and move on.

Comment: There's no need to explicitly write `<t>` inside the class because of [injected class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549652/why-is-there-an-injected-class-name).

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1**

Declare the functions before the definition of the class template.

```
template <typename t> class Number;

template <typename t>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Number<t>& a);

template <typename t>
Number<t> operator%(Number<t> a, Number<t> b);
```

Define the class. Make sure the `friend` declarations use the template parameter.

```
template <typename t>
class Number
{
private:
    t n;
public:
    Number(t a) :n{ a } {};
    Number() :n{ t() } {};

    // This makes sure that operator<< <int> is a friend of Number<int>
    // but not of Number<double>
    friend std::ostream & operator<< <t>(std::ostream & os, const Number& a);
    friend Number operator%<t>(Number a, Number b);
};
```

Implement the functions outside the class definition.

```
template <typename t>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Number<t>& a)
{
    os << a.n;
    return os;
}

template <typename t> 
Number<t> operator%(Number<t> a, Number<t> b)
{
    return Number(a.n % b.n);
}
```

Working code at http://ideone.com/dx3fC0.

**Method 2**

Implement the `friend` functions inside the class template definition.

```
template <typename t>
class Number
{
   private:
      t n;
   public:
      Number(t a) :n{ a } {};
      Number() :n{ t() } {};
      friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Number& a)
      {
         os << a.n;
         return os;
      }

      friend Number operator%(Number a, Number b)
      {
         return Number<t>(a.n % b.n);
      }
};
```

Working code at http://ideone.com/5PYQnR.

---

If the `friend` functions are not overly complex, it is better to use the second method. The overall code structure is simple. If the `friend` functions are complex, it might make sense to use the first method and implement them outside the class definition.

Comment: Thank you. I think I get get what's really going on inside the class now: template specialization of the above declaration. And because the template of `Number` will be specialized after when it's finally put into use, we should be able to pull one more dodge and fully define the templated functions ahead of the definition of `Number`. That will be really freaky because it now looks like we're using parts of `Number` before they've been defined.

Comment: @user4581301, *That will be really freaky because it now looks like we're using parts of Number before they've been defined.* There is an established pattern called [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) that does exactly that.

Comment: better yet, implement binary operators in terms of unary operators and/or methods. then you don't need them to be friends.

Answer (score 1):

You should first declare the operator as a function template before "befriending" it in the class. See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Template_friend_operators) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660123/overloading-friend-operator-for-template-class) for more details on how to properly do that.

The reason you got away with `operator <<` I suspect, is a `using namespace std` not shown in your question, which brings in the templated `operator <<` declaration from `<iostream>`.

This should work:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Number;

// Declare the operators here.
template<typename T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Number<T>& a);

template<typename T>
Number<T> operator%(Number<T> a, Number<T> b);

template<typename T>
class Number
{
private:
    T n;
public:
    Number(T a) :n{ a } {};
    Number() :n{ T() } {};

    friend std::ostream & operator<< <T>(std::ostream & os, const Number& a);

    friend Number operator% <T>(Number a, Number b);
};

template<typename T>
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Number<T>& a /* was Number<T> ==> signature mismatch */) 
{
    os << a.n;
    return os;
}

template<typename T> 
Number<T> operator%(Number<T> a, Number<T> b)
{
    return Number<T>(a.n % b.n);
}

int main() {
    Number<int> a(5);
    Number<int> b(6);
    auto c = a % b;
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define these functions in the class body and save yourself the hassle.  Also, in case that the left-hand side operand of `%` is `Number` you don't have to make it a friend.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::ostream;

template<typename t>
class Number
{
private:
    t n;
public:
    Number(t a) :n{ a } {};
    Number() :n{ t() } {};

    Number operator%(Number rhs)
    {
        return Number(n % rhs.n);
    }

    friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, Number a)
    {
       os << a.n;
       return os;
    }
};


int main()
{
  Number<int> n1(4);
  Number<int> n2(2);

  std::cout << n1 << ' ' << n2 << '\n';

  Number<int> n3 = n1 % n2;
  std::cout << n3 << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the friend operator a templated operator itself:

```
template<typename t>
class Number
{
private:
    t n;
public:
    Number(t a) :n ( a ){};
    Number() :n( t() ) {};

    template<typename TT>
    friend Number<TT> operator%(Number<TT> a,const Number<TT>& b);
};

template<typename t> 
Number<t> operator%(Number<t> a,const Number<t> &b)
{
    return Number<t>(a.n % b.n);
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Number<int> a;
    Number<int> b;

    Number<int> c = a %b;
    return 0;
}
```

See explanation about extrovert declaration [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4661372/536086).