# Can an injected-class-name be used in a friend statement?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

The following example fails to compile in Visual Studio 2015:

```
namespace ns {
    template<typename T> class MyClass;

    template<typename T>
    T Func(const MyClass<T> &a);

    template<typename T>
    class MyClass {
        // (1) With template type, without namespace: compiles
        //friend T Func<T>(const MyClass<T> &a);
        // (2) With template type, with namespace: compiles
        //friend T ns::Func<T>(const MyClass<T> &a);
        // (3) Without template type, without namespace: compiles
        //friend T Func<T>(const MyClass &a);
        // (4) Without template type, with namespace: doesn't compile
        friend T ns::Func<T>(const MyClass &a);
    };
}

int main() {
    ns::MyClass<int> a;
    return 0;
}
```

My understanding of [injected class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549652/why-is-there-an-injected-class-name) is that `MyClass` is sufficient to identify `MyClass<T>` within the confines of the class itself.  However depending on the namespace-qualification of `Func`, Visual Studio 2015 fails to compile the friend definition unless `MyClass<t>` is used.

Note that this example compiles on at least gcc 5.1.  Is this a MSVC bug, or is something else going on here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the answer is **yes, the name is injected**. Lots of code use this feature when writing custom `friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& lhs, const Foo& foo);`. I don't have a reference so I won't post this as an answer.