# Correct signature for template class method that returns its own type

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates, operator-overloading

My particular case involves a custom iterator, but this question is a general one. I'm unsure how to write the return type for this postfix increment method:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyIterator {
    size_t loc;

    MyIterator operator++(int) {
        MyIterator temp(*this);
        ++loc;
        return temp;
    }
};
```

This compiles, but so does this:

```
template<typename T>
struct MyIterator {

    size_t loc;

    MyIterator<T> operator++(int) {
        MyIterator<T> temp(*this);
        ++loc;
        return temp;
    }
};
```

The two other configurations also work fine (i.e. putting the `<T>` on only one of the instances of `MyIterator`). Is there a "correct" way to write this? Does it matter?

Comment: It doesn't matter.  What you are seeing is the *injected class name*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is there a "correct" way to write this?

Both names are correct. However, using the injected class name is simpler and preferable, especially if there are more than one template parameters. Imagine you have:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3> class MyClass { ... };
```

Inside the class template, it is preferable to use `MyClass` than `MyClass<T1, T2, T3>`.

> Does it matter?

No.

Since you are inside the scope of the class, the name lookup will find what you expect.  This has to do with **injected class name**, and I suggest you to read more about it here: [Why is there an injected class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549652/why-is-there-an-injected-class-name)

---

Since [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14), another correct way to do it is `auto` with no trailing return type, as skypjack mentioned.

Comment: Another _correct_ way to do it is `auto` with no trailing return type since C++14.

Comment: Thank you @skypjack, improved my answer!