# Why is T::T::T::T::T::T the same as T for a class name?

Tags: c++, class, scope

Consider the following "code":

```
struct T
{
    T();
    static int x;
};

T::T::T::T::T::T()
{
}

int T::x;

int main()
{
    T t1;
    T::T t2;
    T* p=static_cast<T::T::T::T*>(&t1);
    T::T::T::T::T::x=5;
}
```

It compiles with both g++ from 4.7 to 8 and clang++ from 3.5 to 6 without any errors or relevant warnings with `-pedantic-errors`. Apparently, class name followed by scope resolution operator can be repeated without affecting meaning of the class type being named — as if the class is nested inside itself.

Is it a bug in compilers? Or is the C++ language really defined in such a way that it tolerates such abuse?

If it's really standard-conforming C++ code, is there any rationale for allowing this, or is it just to simplify wording of the Standard?

Comment: VS2017 is fine with `T::T::T::T::T::T() {}` but not with any of the other odd cases you've shown here. Edit : It's also fine with `T::T::T::T::T::x=5;`. It seems it's fine when used to ultimately indicate a member but not to indicate the type itself.

Comment: doesn't compile with recent version of clang or gcc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549652/why-is-there-an-injected-class-name