# Why does having a declaration of a private base class render a type name inaccessible?

Tags: c++, injected-class-name

I am surprised that in the following example declaring Middle's base class private makes that name unavailable as a type in a subsequent derivation.

```
class Base {
public:
  Base(Base const& b) : i(b.i) {}

  int i;
};

class Middle : private Base {            //<<<<<<<<<<<
public:
  Middle(Base const* p) : Base(*p) {}
};

class Upper : public Middle {
public:
  Upper(Base const* p) : Middle(p) {}    //<<<<<<<<<<<
};
```

Compiling thusly with g++ (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516...

```
g++ -std=c++11 privateBase.cpp
```

I get the following diagnostics:

```
privateBase.cpp:15:9: error: ‘class Base Base::Base’ is inaccessible within this context
   Upper(Base const* p) : Middle(p) {}
         ^~~~
privateBase.cpp:1:12: note: declared here
 class Base {
            ^
```

Clearly at the point that Base was used as Middle's base class its name was available as a type.  I can understand that when Base is used to denote base class storage that should be private.  But having a declaration of a private base class render a type name inaccessible seems, at the very least, unexpected.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is intended; see [core issue 175](https://wg21.link/CWG175), which even added an example illustrating this in [class.access.spec]p5:

> [ *Note:* In a derived class, the lookup of a base class name will find
>   the injected-class-name instead of the name of the base class in the
>   scope in which it was declared. The injected-class-name might be less
>   accessible than the name of the base class in the scope in which it
>   was declared. — *end note* ] [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> class A { };
> class B : private A { };
> class C : public B {
>   A* p;             // error: injected-class-name A is inaccessible
>   ::A* q;           // OK
> };
> ```
>
> — *end example* ]

---

This falls out of the interaction between class name injection (for rationale, see [Why is there an injected class name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549652/why-is-there-an-injected-class-name)) and the fact that in C++ access control applies after name lookup, not before.

Comment: You forgot to explain why.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - is this [cppreference explanation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name) sufficient:  "In a class scope, the name of the current class is treated _as if it were a public member name_; this is called injected-class-name. The point of declaration of the name is immediately following the opening brace of the class definition.  _Like other members, injected-class-names are inherited._ In the presence of private or protected inheritance, the injected-class-name of an indirect base class might end up being inaccessible in a derived class."  (Italics added.)

Comment: Yes, that will suffice.

Comment: As a guess, the issue is about preventing names from changing when an access specifier changes. Suppose there are both `A` in global scope and `ns::A` in the namespace `ns`, and the base is specified as `ns::A`. In that case, `A` in the derived class refers to `ns::A`. Making the base private shouldn't turn that into `::A`.

Comment: A related but O.T. question:  Are there languages where access control applies during name lookup rather than after?  (Just curious.  I find access control an interesting part of C++/Java/C#.  It seems to be an invention for software engineering purposes as it is not part of O-O theory - at least not so far as _Theory of Objects_ (Abadi, Cardelli) is concerned.  And the ur-pure O-O language Smalltalk doesn't have access modifiers...)

Comment: @davidbak: Access control is part of encapsulation.  It is the very essence of OO.