# C++ using 'this' keyword in member initialization list

Tags: c++

I was writing an Integer struct

```
struct Integer
{
    int value;
    Integer(int value_) : value(_value){ }
};
```

This works fine but instead I wanted to use *value* name for the parameter too and this causes a name clash. That's why I tried to use *this* keyword like below

```
struct Integer
{
    int value;
    Integer(int value) : this->value(value){ }
};
```

But I got an error and I don't seem to understand the problem here. I would be very happy to learn. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: It *shouldn't* clash. The names in the initializer list are always members or constructors, while the name inside the parentheses will always be the argument.

Comment: "The names in the initializer list are always members or " **classes**. Constructors don't have names, classes do. Just noting so you can find the correct name lookup rules. E.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549652/why-is-there-an-injected-class-name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This works fine but instead I wanted to use value name for the parameter too and this causes a name clash.

No it doesn't.

```
Integer(int value) : value(value){ }
```

This is just fine (if a little confusing to some).

It is simply not permitted in the language grammar to write `this->` there, probably because it would make no sense to specify any *other* object: the `this->` is implicitly done for you.

Answer (score 5):

The standard way is to write

```
struct Integer
{
    int value;
    Integer(int value) : value(value){ }
};
```

In the initializer list `: value(value)`, the first `value` refers to the member (because that's what a member initializer initializes), while the second `value` refers to the constructor argument (because that's an expression, and the name in an expression is looked up by the ordinary rules).

Answer (score 1):

As other answers already mentioned, it is not defined in the C++grammer / syntax.
See it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

And there is no need to specify `this`. To disambiguate class vs. member you don't use `this`, you use the scope resoultion operator.

See this (strange) example:

```
#include <iostream>


class A{
public:
    A(int a){
        std::cout << "A("<< a << ")\n";
    }
    A(){
        std::cout << "A()\n";
    }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    int A;
     B(int a) : A::A(42), A(a)
    {}
};

int main()
{  
    B b = 12;
    std::cout << b.A;
    return 0;
}
```

And of course this already *exists*:

```
#include <iostream>

class B;

class A{
public:
    A(int a){
        std::cout << "A("<< a << ")\n";
    }
    A(){
        std::cout << "A()\n";
    }
    A(B& b);
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    int A;
     B(int a) : A::A(*this), A(a)
    {}
};

inline A::A(B& b){
    std::cout << "A(B&)\n";
}

int main()
{  
    B b = 12;
    std::cout << b.A;
    return 0;
}
```