# Why does C++ name lookup seem inconsistent in this example?

Tags: c++

I have following C++ code:

```
template <typename Type, typename T>
class zz
{
};

class foo
{
  template <typename T>
  using zz = ::zz<foo, T>;
  
  struct own_type : zz<double>
  {
    own_type():
      zz<foo, double>{} {} // ERROR: needs foo arg !!
  };
  
  template <typename T>
  struct zz_type_gen : zz<T>
  {
    zz_type_gen():
      zz<T>() {}
  };

  zz<int> _oi;
  zz_type_gen<char> _od;
};
```

Compiling with g++ 11, clang++ 12 and cl.exe with -std=c++20 works fine but if foo template argument is removed in line with // ERROR comment compilation fails.
This seems to indicate that `zz` name is looked up first in global namespace inside nested class in case nested class (`own_type`) is not template. However `zz` name is looked up first in `class foo` in case nested class is template (`zz_type_gen`).
I could not find clear explanation on how C++ names lookup works, but intuitively this seems inconsistent.

Comment: Pretty sure this has to do with the two pass compilation that templates go through.  With `own_type`, since it is not a template the compiler knows that `zz<double>` gives you the class `zz<foo, double>`, and because of [injected class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549652/why-is-there-an-injected-class-name), your zz alias gets hidden.  With  `zz_type_gen` , `zz<T>` is a dependant name so the compiler doesn't know what the injected class name will be, so it allows `zz<T>`.  FWIW, renaming your alias to `zz_foo_t` or something like that would fix all of this.

Comment: Thanks, yes having different names is the path I'll go, much less surprises, but wanted to get some explanation on apparent inconsistent behavior.

Comment: You can also say `own_type() : zz{} {}` or `own_type() : foo::zz<double>{} {}`.

Comment: @NathanOliver "your zz alias gets hidden" But then why isn't `::zz` hidden? Why, if you rename `foo::zz` alias to `foo::yy`, it doesn't get hidden the same way? It only happens when a nested alias aliases a global template of the same name. It does not happen when the nested alias aliases anything else (and a global template with the same name still exists but unrelated), and it doesn't happen when the nested template is not an alias.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Classes inject their name into the class scope.  When you inherit from `zz<foo, double>`, it introduces that name into the scope of the derived class.  That name being in scope stops lookup in the surrounding scope.

Comment: @NathanOliver oh got it. Here's a more accessible (to me) explanation: `own_type : zz<double> {...}` is exactly the same as `own_type : ::zz<foo, double> {...}`, and what is injected is `::zz`, not `foo::zz`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Exactly.  Because `own_type` is not a template, the compiler knows all of this, and the name hiding rule causes the error.  With `zz_type_gen`, it's doesn't know what name `zz<T>` will resolve to, so it lets it go.  At least, that's what I suspect.

Comment: @NathanOliver seems plausible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To allow

```
namespace N {
  struct A {int f();};
}
struct B : N::A {
  int f() {return A::f()+1;}
};
```

without repeating the namespace qualification of `A`, and for the similar case of not repeating the template arguments of a class template, each class is considered to declare itself as a **member** (although this syntax is also used to declare or inherit constructors).

To prevent (specializations of) dependent base classes from **shadowing** names used in templated classes, unqualified name lookup is performed immediately in the template definition and ignores such bases entirely.  This has the odd interaction with the injected-class-name model that even a name that would obviously refer to the base in each instantiation is sought **outside** the class instead.  This does provide consistency with the case where the dependent base is more complicated than a *template-id* that names some specialization of a particular class template.

Therefore, `own_type` finds the injected-class-name of its base, which can be used either as a *type-name* (by omitting `<foo, double>`) or as the *template-name* that `::z` is.  `zz_type_gen`, however, finds `foo::zz`; it could use `typename zz_type_gen::zz` to find the injected-class-name instead of repeating the template argument list.  (C++20 dispenses with the requirement for `typename` in some contexts but not others; a *mem-initializer* still requires it, but that was likely an oversight.)