# Why does a class/struct have it's own namespace accesible through scope resolution operator?

Tags: c++, class, oop

I accidentally noticed that you can pointlessly use :: operator to reefer back to the original struct/class again, for example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Test
{
    static const int x = 5;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << Test::x;              // makes sense
    std::cout << Test::Test::x;        // still works?
    std::cout << Test::Test::Test::x;  // okay...
    return 0;
}
```

This can be stacked more and more. However, you can't construct an object this way, because compiler doesn't recognize it as a type, but interprets it as a class::constructor.

```
Test::Test Obj; // error, not a type
```

Although if there was a nested class inside, then you could still reference it this way and successfully construct an object.

I was wondering what leads to this, is this a side effect of something else? It seems totally useless but made me curious.

Comment: This is the [injected class name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name).

Comment: @RaymondChen Thank you, I couldn't find this through google search.

Comment: Yes, I will add an answer pointing out that my questions was a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

This is [injected class name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name), simmilar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25549652/why-is-there-an-injected-class-name)