# Correct syntax for constructor using declaration inherited from a template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a templated base class in a namespace (not sure if that's relevant, so including it just in case). I am trying to extend the class with a `using` declaration for the constructors, and call one of the methods:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

namespace ns
{

template <typename T>
class Base
{
public:
    Base(const std::shared_ptr<const T> x): p{std::move(x)} {}
    Base(const T &x): Base{std::shared_ptr<const T>(&x)} {}
    Base(T &&x): Base{std::make_shared<const T>(std::move(x))} {}

    T getP() { return *p; }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> p;
};

} // ns

template <typename T>
class Test : public ns::Base<T>
{
public:
    using ns::Base::Base;

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << getP() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test<int> t{3};
    t.print();
}
```

Given `using ns::Base::Base;`, I get the following error:

```
snip.cpp:26:15: error: ‘template<class T> class ns::Base’ used without template arguments
   26 |     using ns::Base::Base;
      |               ^~~~
```

Changing that to `using ns::Base<T>::Base;` gets past the constructor line, but can't find the definition of the method:

```
snip.cpp: In member function ‘void Test<T>::print()’:
snip.cpp:30:22: error: there are no arguments to ‘getP’ that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of ‘getP’ must be available [-fpermissive]
   30 |         std::cout << getP() << std::endl;
      |                      ^~~~
snip.cpp:30:22: note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’, G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
snip.cpp: In instantiation of ‘ns::Base<T>::Base(std::shared_ptr<const _Tp>) [with T = int]’:
snip.cpp:13:62:   required from ‘ns::Base<T>::Base(T&&) [with T = int]’
snip.cpp:26:24:   required from here
snip.cpp:11:59: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::shared_ptr<int>::shared_ptr(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   11 |     Base(const std::shared_ptr<const T> x): p{std::move(x)} {}
      |                                                           ^
```

How do I use a templated base class in an extension so that I can reuse the base constructors and call the methods?

Comment: `this->getP()` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik. That's amazingly effective. Not to look a gift horse in the mouth, but why?

Comment: Shouldn't `using ns::Base::Base;` be `using ns::Base<T>::Base;` instead? Also, why use `shared_ptr` at all? You are not sharing ownership of it with anyone. And `Base(const T &x): Base{std::shared_ptr<const T>(&x)} {}` looks very dangerous, it will only be safe to use if `x` was created with `new` and then dereferenced when passed to `Base()`.

Comment: `using Test::Base::Base;`  also works, and is far less cumbersome when there are many arguments to repeat.

Comment: And as for the canonical on accessing dependent bases https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643074/why-do-i-have-to-access-template-base-class-members-through-the-this-pointer

Comment: @RemyLebeau. The `shared_ptr` stuff is there just to illustrate that there are some non-trivial constructors. I'm doing some stuff with a library that has the base template. Your comment about the reference is duly noted.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica. The canonical answer is much appreciated. Could you explain the use of `Test::Base...` a bit more?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica alternatively, if you have a good reference question for that, we can close this as a supplicate of the two questions

Comment: I couldn't find a Q that wasn't just tengential or broader. The gist is simply `Test::` making name lookup dependent (like `this->` in other contexts), so we can find the [injected class mame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25549652/817643) of the base.

Comment: *"not sure if that's relevant"* -- It's not hard to find out if it is. Remove the namespace from your example, compile it, and see if the error persists. If it does, then the namespace is not necessary. If it doesn't, and if you didn't miss removing a `ns::`, then it is relevant.

Comment: @JaMiT. Fair point.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I am not worried about the broadening of the scope. The question you linked explains everything perfectly. Much appreciated!